# Can I ask for a re-stamp on my passport at Incheon airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, south-korea, icn

Is there an immigration office in Incheon Airport (Korea)? Can I re-stamp my stamp for my arrival because my passport got wet and the stamp was washed out and it can be barely seen.

Comment: I don't think you need to physically go to an office, or necessarily do anything at all.  South Korea will have electronic records of your arrival in the country, which will pop up on departure; they don't *need* the physical stamp.

Answer (score 6):

There is an immigration office behind G check-in counter on the 3rd floor of main terminal. More details can be found on [leaflet](http://www.airport.kr/pa/en/file/Airport%20Guide-English.pdf).

Btw it would be better to ask the information desk first.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but looking deeply into their [website](http://www.airport.kr/), I can't see one.
In my opinion, your best bet would be going there and asking at an information desk. They will probably speak good enough English (if it is your main language), otherwise, you can use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) on your phone to talk in the worst case. Good Luck!